# Nginx Docker Container - forwarding php-file requests to php-fpm container

Tags: php, docker, nginx, raspberry-pi

I already asked the same question on superuser (https://superuser.com/questions/1298776/nginx-execute-php-files-in-different-docker-container) but it was not possible to get an answer, maybe this problem is too specific for SU.

I am using an automated docker-image for php-fpm and nginx (https://hub.docker.com/r/tobi312/rpi-php/ and https://hub.docker.com/r/tobi312/rpi-nginx/ ) running on a raspberry pi with with libreelec on top.

The php container successfully starts with port 9000 open by running the following command:

```
docker run --name php -v /var/www/restTools:/var/www/html -d 3dd6ff8c0d58
```

After that I started the nginx-container like this:

```
docker run --name nginx -d -p 8081:80 --link php:9000 -v /var/www/restTools:/var/www/html 0d90cc6eb00f
```

Both containers are running but the nginx is not executing php files, it's just offering them for download.

After a while I tried to commit the connections details to the php-container trough a `default.conf` by adding `-v /var/www/.config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro` to the command.

Excerpt from `default.conf`:

```
root /var/www/html;

location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    root /var/www/html;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $http_x_real_ip;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the (deprecated!!) "link" option of docker, this is not a problem itself, but you have to respect [the syntax](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#communication-across-links)

```
--link <name or id>:alias
```

so, you have to substitute your

```
--link php:9000
```

with the correct

```
--link php
```

you do not need an alias because you named the fpm container the same as you referred it in default.conf.
The other important thing is to mount the php files folder in the fpm container but you already did this right.